# Python Challenge Level 2

Tags: python

I am trying to solve Python challenges in [pythonchallenge.com](http://www.pythonchallenge.com/). I am in level 2. I was asked to find rare characters in a very large text which is given in the source code of the web page. Here it is:
http://www.pythonchallenge.com/pc/def/ocr.html

First of all, I don't want any solutions for this. I just want to solve it on my own but I am not an advanced Python programmer. So can you tell me what to study to solve this? I also don't know how to work with files very well. In some clues on forum, it is mentioned that one should use files to solve this. So can you show me what to study?

Comment: search here on this site. eg: type `python read file`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint 1: To open and read a file's contents, use

```
with open("filename") as f:
    contents = f.read()
```

Hint 2: To count characters, one option is to use a `Counter`.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, read all the characters into a string. You can use [`urllib2`](http://docs.python.org/library/urllib2.html) to download the file, [`open`](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#open) to read it from the local disk, or hardcode its contents. To include such a long string your Python program, you may want to use [triple-quotes](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/introduction.html#strings) strings, as in:

```
"""
%%$@_$^__#)^)&!_+]!*@&^}@[@%]()%+$&[(_@%+%$*^@$^!+]!&_#)_*}{}}!}_]$[%}@[{_@#_^{*
@##&{#&{&)*%(]{{([*}@[@&]+!!*{)!}{%+{))])[!^})+)$]#{*+^((@^@}$[**$&^{$!@#$%)!@(&
...
"""
```

To find out the number of occurences of each character, have a look at [**`collections.Counter`**](http://docs.python.org/library/collections.html#collections.Counter).

Answer (score 2):

Use `Counter` from collections
to count the number of occurences of each to character to find the 'rare' characters.

I'll leave the rest for you to figure out after you view the results of the count.